# how to fix: Array index is out of range

Tags: javascript, arrays, swift, string

i have this problem

Have the function WildcardCharacters(str) read str which will contain two strings separated by a space. The first string will consist of the following sets of characters: +, *, and {N} which is optional. The plus (+) character represents a single alphabetic character, the asterisk (*) represents a sequence of the same character of length 3 unless it is followed by {N} which represents how many characters should appear in the sequence where N will be at least 1. Your goal is to determine if the second string exactly matches the pattern of the first string in the input.

i have the solution with js, but now i am trying to solve with swift, i need your help.

this work with js, and i'm using swift v4.2

code with js

```
function WildcardCharacters(str) { 

  // code goes here 
  let strArr= str.split(' ')
  let specChar = strArr[0]
  let charStr = strArr[1].split('')

  let arr = specChar.split('')
  let letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/
  let i = 0
  while(i< arr.length){
      if(arr[i] == '+'){
          if(!charStr[0].match(letters)) return "false"
         charStr = charStr.slice(1,charStr.length)
      }
      else if(arr[i] == '*'){
          let curr = charStr[0]
          let j = 1, k = 0
          if(arr[i+1] != undefined && arr[i+1] == '{'){
              k = arr[i+2]
              i = i+4
          }else{
              k = 3
              i++
          }

          while(j < k){
            charStr = charStr.slice(1,charStr.length)
            if(charStr[0] != curr) return "false"
            j++
          }
          charStr = charStr.slice(1,charStr.length)
          continue
      }
      i++ 
    }
    if(charStr.length != 0) return 'false'
     return "true" 
}

// keep this function call here 
WildcardCharacters("+++++* abcdemmmmmm");
```

code by Smakar20 (user github)

code with swift

```
extension String {

    func isAlphanumeric() -> Bool {
        return self.rangeOfCharacter(from:         CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted) == nil && self != ""
    }

    func isAlphanumeric(ignoreDiacritics: Bool = false) -> Bool {
        if ignoreDiacritics {
            return self.range(of: "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", options:     .regularExpression) == nil && self != ""
        }
        else {
            return self.isAlphanumeric()
        }
    }

}

func wild (str: String) -> String
{
    let strArr = str.split(separator: " ")
    let specChar = strArr[0]
    var charStr = Array(strArr[1])

    let arr = Array(specChar)

    var i = 0

    while (i<arr.count)
    {
        if arr[i] == "+"
        {
            if !String(charStr[0]).isAlphanumeric()
            {
                return "false"
            }
            charStr = Array(charStr[0...charStr.count])
        }
        else if arr[i] == "*"
        {
            let curr = charStr[0]
            var j = 0
            var k = 0
            if String(arr[i+1]).isAlphanumeric() != true && arr[i+1] == "{"
            {
                k = Int(String(arr[i+2]))!
                i = i+4
            }
            else
            {
                k = 3
                i += 1
            }
            while (j<k)
            {
                charStr = Array(charStr[1...charStr.count])
                if charStr[0] != curr
                {
                    return "false"
                }
                j += 1
            }
            charStr = Array(charStr[1...charStr.count])
            continue
        }
        i += 1
    }
    if charStr.count != 0
    {
        return "false"
    }
    return "true"
}

wild(str: "+++++* abcdemmmmmm")
```

if str is "++*{5} gheeeee" then the second string in this case does match the pattern, so your program should return the string true. If the second string does not match the pattern your program should return the string false.

heeelp

Comment: In Swift you are initializing `j` to `0` and in js it was initialized to `1`.  Did you do that on purpose?

Comment: `charStr[0...charStr.count]` is definitely wrong.

Comment: and accessing an array using `i+1` or `i+2` looks like trouble as well when the loop condition is `i<arr.count`. When I change `...charStr.count` to `..<charStr.count` the code doesn't crash until `i` is 5 with an "Index out of range" error